# Chrome DevTools showing only partial line in console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Working in Chrome DevTools in the console tab, I can only see the top part of the line that I enter.  Does anyone know how to get this back to normal? [image: Chrome DevTools partial line issue]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to reduce scaling, try Ctrl + 0 or Ctrl + "-"

Comment: @wallwalker I've one more idea, if you working under Windows, can you verify windows screen scaling options, try to set it 100%.